# How to bind 3 or more variables with 1:1 relationships in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-binding

Suppose I wish to make unit converter in AngularJS. Also I would like that multiple values change simultaneously on edit.

This means, for example, that if we have 3 variables, then on change of each one, 2 other should change automatically.

Is this possible?

Below is a not working snippet of 3 units of distance, petameters, light years and parsecs:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myControllers']);

var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers', []);

myControllers
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.petameters = 10;
    $scope.lightyears = $scope.petameters / 9.460730472580800;
    $scope.parsecs = $scope.lightyears / 3.2616;
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        Petameters:<input type="text" ng-model="petameters"><br/>
          Light years:<input type="text" ng-model="lightyears"><br/>
          Parsecs:<input type="text" ng-model="parsecs"><br/>
    </div>
</body>
```

How to make it work?

**UPDATE**

Finally I composed the following code:

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myControllers']);

var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers', []);

myControllers
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    
    $scope.petametersChanged = function() {
     $scope.lightyears = $scope.petameters / 9.460730472580800;
     $scope.parsecs = $scope.lightyears / 3.2616;
    }
    
    $scope.lightyearsChanged = function() {
     $scope.petameters = $scope.lightyears * 9.460730472580800;
     $scope.parsecs = $scope.lightyears / 3.2616;
    }
    
    $scope.parsecsChanged = function() {
     $scope.lightyears = $scope.parsecs * 3.2616;
      $scope.petameters = $scope.lightyears * 9.460730472580800;
    }
    
    $scope.petameters = 10;
    $scope.petametersChanged();
    
  }]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyController">
        Petameters:<input type="text" ng-model="petameters" ng-change="petametersChanged()"><br/>
          Light years:<input type="text" ng-model="lightyears" ng-change="lightyearsChanged()"><br/>
          Parsecs:<input type="text" ng-model="parsecs" ng-change="parsecsChanged()"><br/>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: You need to use `ng-input/ng-keypress` or similar event on all the inputs and call function which will update the `lightyears` and `parsecs`.

Comment: write 3 different ng-change for the three inputs. done. you can do it in one function but it would be with if/else and not a good code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

JS

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['myControllers']);

var myControllers = angular.module('myControllers', []);

myControllers
  .controller('MyController', ['$scope',
    function($scope) {
      $scope.petameters;
      $scope.lightyears;
      $scope.parsecs;

      $scope.update = function(unit) {
        console.log('In Update');
        if(unit === 1) {
          $scope.lightyears = $scope.petameters / 9.460730472580800;
          $scope.parsecs = $scope.lightyears / 3.2616;
        } else if(unit === 2) {
          $scope.petameters = $scope.lightyears * 9.460730472580800;
          $scope.parsecs = $scope.lightyears / 3.2616;
        } else {
          $scope.lightyears = $scope.parsecs * 3.2616;
          $scope.petameters = $scope.lightyears * 9.460730472580800;
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
```

html

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyController">
    Petameters:
    <input type="text" ng-model="petameters" ng-keyup="update(1)" />
    <br/>Light years:
    <input type="text" ng-model="lightyears" ng-keyup="update(2)" />
    <br/>Parsecs:
    <input type="text" ng-model="parsecs" ng-keyup="update(3)" />
    <br/>
  </div>
</body>
```

Here is the [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/i6WgT98CG7V5zKoeWXuA?p=preview)